# having a background image for a specific time only

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to make a div have a background image but only for a specific time:
pseudo code:
div has background image, after 1 sec passed div has background none,
anyway doing this in jquery?
regards

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) in `jQuery` 1.4+

`$('#someDivID').delay(1000).css('background', 'none');`

Otherwise you can use `setTimeout`:

`setTimeout(function() { $('#someDivID').css('background', 'none'); }, 1000);`

Comment: sorry , the numbers of milli or sec is whatever.(my bad for the syntax)

Comment: @tada it's in miliseconds. A good way of finding that out is just googling *setTimeout javascript* and looking at what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.removebg")
    .delay(1000000) // miliseconds
    .animate{
    background: 'none'
}, 
100);
```

Comment: The question asks for a 1000/sec delay, which can be understood as 1 million ms...

Comment: Yeah I thought 1000 sec - he should've written 1 second if he wanted 1000ms